# Adobe air application quits when i try to print after a function called "show bill"?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, air, desktop

I am trying to create an air application using flash profession cc. I have functions called show bill and print bill in it. When i print directly with out showing the bill adobe air application works correctly. But when i try to use the show bill function and then try to print the bill  it show the print dialog box and when i give a print command an"Adobe Air Application Stop working window shows up" . Here is the code of show bill function

```
public function ShowBill(e: MouseEvent): void {
        total();
        Merge();
        bswap();
        billing.x = 450;
        billing.y = 100;
        billing.height = 300 ;
        billing.width = 500 ;
        addChild(billing);
        billing.close_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rmvBilling);
        billing.close_btn1.visible = true;
        if(billing._item.item1.text != "")
        {
            billing._item.visible = true;
            billing._item.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item2.item1.text != "")
        {
        item2.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item3.item1.text != "")
        {
        item3.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item4.item1.text != "")
        {
        item4.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item5.item1.text != "")
        {
        item5.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item6.item1.text != "")
        {
        item6.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item7.item1.text != "")
        {
        item7.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item8.item1.text != "")
        {
        item8.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item9.item1.text != "")
        {
        item9.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }
        if(item10.item1.text != "")
        {
        item10.close_btn1.visible = true;
        }

        total();
    }
```

Here is the code for print bill

```
public function printContent(e: MouseEvent) {
        update1();
        billing.close_btn1.visible = false;
        billing._item.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item2.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item3.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item4.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item5.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item6.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item7.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item8.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item9.close_btn1.visible = false;
        item10.close_btn1.visible = false;

        var printJob: PrintJob = new PrintJob();
        if (printJob.start()) {
                if (billing.width < printJob.pageWidth) {
                    billing.width = printJob.pageWidth;
                    billing.scaleY = billing.scaleX;
                }
                printJob.addPage(billing);
                printJob.send();
                clear();
            }

    }
    public function update1():void{
        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/icyspicy/update.php");
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;
        var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        phpVars.systemCall="update";
        phpVars.table = String(tabNbill1.getDubTblNo.text);
        phpVars.date = String(billing.the_date.text);
        phpVars.items = String(billing._item.item1.text+","+item2.item1.text+","+item3.item1.text+","+item4.item1.text+","+item5.item1.text+","+item6.item1.text+","+item7.item1.text+","+item8.item1.text+","+item9.item1.text+","+item10.item1.text );
        phpVars.quantity = String(billing._item.q2.text+","+item2.q2.text+","+item3.q2.text+","+item4.q2.text+","+item5.q2.text+","+item6.q2.text+","+item7.q2.text+","+item8.q2.text+","+item9.q2.text+","+item10.q2.text);
        phpVars.total =String( billing.total.text);
        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
        postData(mypath, getResponse);
    }
```

Every function is working correctly but the conflict between printbill and show bill i could not solve ..Please guys need suggestion and help..Thank You

Comment: The application is force closed . Its stops working as soon as i do a show bill and then do a printing.Sorry i forgot to mention that my first .fla file on which i was working was corrupted . Then i have created a new .fla file as it was before but then these force application closing  started. @LDMS

Comment: You could try converting your `billing` object to a bitmap.   Also, best practice is to wrap any `printJob.addPage()` calls in a try catch.  It could be that it's failing for some reason and then the call to `printJobsend()` is crashing the app.

Comment: thanks @LDMS i ll try doing that

Comment: Another important question I suppose,  is does it have the same result on multiple computers/printers?  And does it crash before or after the print dialog comes up?   It would be good if you edited your question to include those details.

Comment: Nope .. it still not working with try catch block . I used try catch on printContent function.@LDMS

Comment: Try printing as bitmap.   `printJob.addPage(billing, null, new PrintJobOptions(true));`  Could also try using `start2` instead of `start` since you're using AIR - I think when I had this same problem, NOT showing the printer dialog worked (second parameter on the start2 function)

Comment: Thanks @LDMS ... printJob.addPage(billing, null, new PrintJobOptions(true)); .... these code solved the problem . Now i can show the bill as well as print it . Thanks you very much.@LMDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes spooling display objects with text and shapes can crash the application.  While I can't comment on the why,  I can share what I've done in the past to work around this problem.

Printing the page as a bitmap can sometimes fix this crashing problem. In your case that would like this:

```
var printOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions();
printOptions.printAsBitmap = true;

printJob.addPage(billing,null,printOptions);
```

OR for a shorter inline way:

```
printJob.addPage(billing, null, new PrintJobOptions(true));
```

Do note, that sometimes doing this makes text not as crisp looking, as FlashPlayer is basically drawing the object to pixel data before sending it to the spooler.

Comment: Your solution was perfect @LMDS. Actually  I am new to building Air Application so i don't know much how to solve most of the problems. Any way I really really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out.  Printing is one of things that can drive many a developer to pull their hair out - it's not much fun in most programming languages.

Comment: Really , I feel lucky then because i have you guys and a stack overflow..but to tell you the truth i was pissed to ...because i cant figure out what was the problem.